# Xmas Maths 2015

Tags: integration, summation, physics, recreational-mathematics

Simplify the expression below into a seasonal greeting using commonly-used symbols in commonly-used formulas in maths and physics. Colours are purely ornamental!

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{
\color{green}{(x+iy)}
\color{red}{(y^3-x^3)}
\color{orange}{(v^2-u^2)}
\color{red}{(3V_{\text{sphere}})^{\frac 13}}
\color{orange}{E\cdot} 
\color{green}{\text{KE}}
}
{
\color{orange}{2^{\frac 23}}
\color{green}{c^2}
\color{red}{e^{i\theta}}
\color{orange}{v^2}
\color{green}{(x^2+xy+y^2)}}
\color{red}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac 1{n!}}
\color{orange}{\bigg/}
\color{orange}{\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx\right)^{\frac 23}}
\end{align}$$

NB: Knowledge of the following would be helpful:

Basic Maths:

- Taylor series expansion
- Normalizing factor for the integral of a normal distribution
- Rectangular and polar forms for complex variables
- Volume of a sphere

Basic Physics:

- Kinematics formulae for motion under constant acceleration
- Einstein's equation
- One of the energy equations

Comment: I can just see some people say, "Bah, humbug!"  ;)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII - Haha. Well I take all comments constructively and try to address them where possible (hence the edits for context).

Comment: And [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120320051555AAaO0a9)'s the only thing I could not get of this expression's simplification below :).

Comment: @hypergeometric Did you made it? Very exciting question!

Comment: @MickG - I hope it's clearer now, but please post a comment if it's not the case. Thanks for reading!

Comment: @Nilanjan - Yes I did... just for some Xmas cheer :) Thanks - glad you like it!

Comment: Alternatively $ y = \frac{ln(\frac{x}{m} - sa)}{r^2} $ ;)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{
\color{green}{(x+iy)}
\color{red}{(y^3-x^3)}
\color{orange}{(v^2-u^2)}
\color{red}{(3V_{\text{sphere}})^{\frac 13}}
\color{orange}{E\cdot} 
\color{green}{\text{KE}}
}
{
\color{orange}{2^{\frac 23}}
\color{green}{c^2}
\color{red}{e^{i\theta}}
\color{orange}{v^2}
\color{green}{(x^2+xy+y^2)}}
\color{red}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac 1{n!}}
\color{orange}{\bigg/}
\color{orange}{\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx\right)^{\frac 23}}\\
&=
\frac{
\color{green}{(x+iy)}
\color{red}{(y^3-x^3)}
\color{orange}{(v^2-u^2)}
\color{red}{(3V_{\text{sphere}})^{\frac 13}}
\color{orange}{E\cdot} 
\color{green}{\text{KE}}
}
{
\color{red}{e^{i\theta}}
\color{green}{(x^2+xy+y^2)}
\color{orange}{\cdot2^{\frac 23}}
\color{green}{c^2}
\color{orange}{v^2}
}
\color{red}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac 1{n!}}
\color{orange}{\bigg/}
\color{orange}{\left(\sqrt{\pi}\right)^{\frac 23}}\\
&=
\color{green}{\left(\frac{x+iy}{e^{i\theta}}\right)}
\color{red}{\left(\frac{y^3-x^3}{x^2+xy+y^2}\right)}
\color{orange}{(v^2-u^2)}
\color{red}{\left(\frac {(3V_\text{sphere})^\frac 13}{\left(2\sqrt{\pi}\right)^{\frac 23}}\right)}
\color{orange}{\left(\frac{E}{c^2}\right)}
\color{green}{\left(\frac{\text{KE}}{v^2}\right)}
\color{red}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac 1{n!}}
\\
&=
\color{green}{\left(\frac{re^{i\theta}}{e^{i\theta}}\right)}
\color{red}{\left(\frac{(y-x)(y^2+xy+x^2)}{x^2+xy+y^2}\right)}
\color{orange}{(v^2-u^2)}
\color{red}{\left(\frac {3\cdot \frac 43 \pi r^3}{4\pi}\right)^\frac 13}
\color{orange}{\left(\frac{mc^2}{c^2}\right)}
\color{green}{\left(\frac{\frac 12 mv^2}{v^2}\right)}
\color{red}{(e)}
\\
&=
\color{green}{\left(r\right)}
\color{red}{\left(y-x\right)}
\color{orange}{(2as)}
\color{red}{\left(r^3\right)^\frac 13}
\color{orange}{\left(m\right)}
\color{green}{\left(\frac 12m\right)}
\color{red}{(e)}
\\
&=
\color{green}{\left(r\right)}
\color{red}{\left(y-x\right)}
\color{orange}{(as)}
\color{red}{\left(r\right)}
\color{orange}{\left(m\right)}
\color{green}{\left( m\right)}
\color{red}{(e)}
\\
&=
\color{orange}{\left(m\right)}
\color{red}{(e)}
\color{green}{\left(r\right)}
\color{red}{\left(r\right)}
\color{red}{\left(y-x\right)}
\color{green}{\left(m\right)}
\color{orange}{(as)}
\end{align}$$

Merry Christmas, everyone!!

---

The following links might be helpful.
- [Complex numbers and polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Complex_numbers)
- [Difference of two cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization#Sum.2Fdifference_of_two_cubes)
- [Kinematics formulae for constant acceleration in a straight line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#Constant_translational_acceleration_in_a_straight_line)
- [Volume of a sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere#Enclosed_volume)
- [Einstein's mass-energy equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence)
- [Kinetic energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy#Kinetic_energy_of_rigid_bodies)
- [Taylor/Maclaurin series expansion of $e$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions)
- [Gaussian integral (normalizing factor for the normal distribution)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral)

Comment: Merry Christmas, my good friend!

Comment: @NimaBavari - Thank you, and to you too!

Answer (score 6):

Notice:

- $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{1}{n!}=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^m=e$$
- $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\space\text{d}x=\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{-a}^{a}e^{-x^2}\space\text{d}x=\lim_{a\to\infty}\left[\frac{\text{erf}(x)\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\right]_{-a}^{a}=\sqrt{\pi}$$
- $$\text{V}_{sphere}=\frac{4\pi r^3}{3}$$
- $$\text{E}=mc^2$$
- $$\text{EK}=\frac{mv^2}{2}$$